# Setting HorizontalContentAlignment from string

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm formatting of column header from string for example background property:

```
var style = new Style(typeof(System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.DataGridColumnHeader));
style.Setters.Add(new Setter(DataGridColumnHeader.BackgroundProperty, new SolidColorBrush((Color)ColorConverter.ConvertFromString("Yellow"))));
```

But I don't know how exactly I can set HorizontalContentAlignment to "Center". I suppose by reflection but I don't know exactly use in this case.

Comment: Usually you don't code styles. Define them as part of your XAML.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Enum.Parse](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.enum.parse?view=netframework-4.7.2) to convert string `"Center"` to corresponding value of type `HorizontalAlignment`:

```
var style = new Style(typeof(System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.DataGridColumnHeader));
var value = Enum.Parse(typeof(HorizontalAlignment), "Center");
var setter = new Setter(Control.HorizontalContentAlignmentProperty, value);
style.Setters.Add(setter);
```